# Excel Regex VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I need to extract a part of string from an excel cell if it matches the following format:
"DDD/L-DDD-L/DDD-L-DD/DD" where D represents any digit and L represents any letter, upper or lower case.

Here are some examples: 
Cell content: "BHL: 200/b-003-A/094-G-08/02" 
Extracted string: "200/b-003-A/094-G-08/02"

Cell content: "UWI: 200/c-098-C/094-G-01/00" 
Extracted string: "200/c-098-C/094-G-01/00"

Cell content: "TOTAL SULPHUR (mass%) = 0.013, BHL: 203/a-044-C/094-G-01/00" 
Extracted string: "203/a-044-C/094-G-01/00"

NOTE: The data formatting is very inconsistent so looking for keywords like "BHL" or "UWI" is not option.

I've made the following VBA function but its not working as expected

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    
    
    strPattern = "[0-9]{3}/[A-Za-z]-[0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z]/[0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z]-[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"
    
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""
        
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .pattern = strPattern
        End With
        
        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Try this regex:
`\d{3}\/[a-zA-Z]-\d{3}-[a-zA-Z]\/\d{3}-[a-zA-Z]-\d{2}\/\d{2}`

Comment: And set `IgnoreCase = True` and use `[a-z]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: You should use `regExp.Execute(strInput)` and look at the returned `Matches` collection

Comment: Will any input cell contain only zero or one instance of the pattern to be matched?

Comment: This be able to handle any regex questions of any kind...
https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you a non-regex/VBA answer; what are the odds that any other part of the cell's content would follow this pattern of forward slashes and hyphens? In other words, would the following work?

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MID(A1:A3,SEARCH("???/?-???-?/???-?-??/??",A1:A3),23)
```

If that type of security isn't enough, you can still do this without regular expressions or VBA:

```
=LET(x,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),23),FILTER(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,LET(z,MID(y,{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,22},{3,1,3,1,3,1,2,2}),AND(AND(ISNUMBER(--CHOOSECOLS(z,{1,3,5,7,8}))),AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CHOOSECOLS(z,{2,4,6}),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("???/?-???-?/???-?-??/??",y)))))),"No Matches"))
```

The breakdown in short:

- `MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),23)` - Get any possible substring in from the input of 23 characters long;
- `MID(y,{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,22},{3,1,3,1,3,1,2,2})` - Create an array of subsequent substring. This will grab all alphanumeric parts;
- `AND(ISNUMBER(--CHOOSECOLS(z,{1,3,5,7,8})))` - Test that the listed columns are all numeric;
- `AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CHOOSECOLS(z,{2,4,6}),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")))` - Test that all listed columns are found in the alphabet (case insensitive);
- `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("???/?-???-?/???-?-??/??",y))` - Test for all forward slashes and hyphens to be in the right place;
- The `FILTER()` will now use the outer `AND()` to return all possible matches (not just one).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `regExp.Execute(strInput)` (not `Replace`) and look at the returned `Matches` collection

This works for me:

```vb
Function simpleCellRegex(v) As String
    Const strPattern = "\d{3}/[A-Z]-\d{3}-[A-Z]/\d{3}-[A-Z]-\d{2}/\d{2}"
    
    Dim regEx As New RegExp, matches As Object, match As Object, sep As String
    
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(v)
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each match In matches
            simpleCellRegex = simpleCellRegex & sep & match.Value
            sep = "; "
        Next match
    Else
        simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference.

You can match the pattern you provided, given the following.

The *(?i)* toggles *case-insensitive* mode, on.
And, *\d* matches any digit, 0 through 9.

```
(?i)\d{3}/[a-z]-\d{3}-[a-z]/\d{3}-[a-z]-\d\d/\d\d
```

Output

```
200/b-003-A/094-G-08/02
200/c-098-C/094-G-01/00
203/a-044-C/094-G-01/00
```